# mapbox bearing and real compass bearings don't match

Tags: api, mapbox, compass-geolocation

I am using the directions API from Mapbox. I was verifying whether the data in "bearing-after" tag and the actual bearing (measured using a mobile compass while facing the desired bearing at the coordinates of maneuver) are same. I came to know that these two readings were drastically different. I verified it using other compass too.

while searching on internet I came to know about the "bearing" and "radius" options that are passed to url during request process, and something about the returned bearings being affected by these parameters, but I don't get what it means (read documentations too, still unclear).

Can someone tell me **why the bearings returned by Mapbox-directions-API and actual compass bearings don't match** and **how to correct this**.

Comment: You do realize that on most places on Earth there is *always* a difference between "real North" and "compass North"? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_declination for starters.

Comment: That completely escaped my mind... i'll do the correction and get back with the results. thank you for the help.

Comment: okay i just found out the declination in my area of concern, its just 0.26 degrees. but my measurements are off by huge values... like 30-40 degrees... i can assure that equipment is not faulty (the equipment offsets have been corrected). what could the problem be ?

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about Mapbox.

Comment: it's okay, thank you for reaching out :)